# html/javascript: Get radio value not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the button to show the value yes or no, but it's only giving me undefined no matter what I click. how can I make it show the correct value of the button selected?

Code is here:

```
<body>

            <form id="Q7" style="display:block">
                <br>
                7. <script type="text/javascript">document.write(Q7)</script><br>
                Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:Q7_check();" name="Q7yesno" id="Q7_Yes" />
                No  <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:Q7_check();" name="Q7yesno" id="Q7_No" />

            </form>
            
            <button onclick="display()">Display value</button>

<script>
function getRadioValue(theRadioGroup)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup);
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i].checked)
        {
            return elements[i].value;
        }
    }
}

function display() {
  var x = getRadioValue('7yesno');
  alert("The value of the radio button is: " + x);
}

</script>
```

I don't want to use the getelementID or document.querySelector('input[name=Q7yesno]:checked').value
there has to be another way so even if there's not a selection, it will still work.

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you told it to do.  So why so surprised by the result?

Comment: But If I click the yes radio button, it's still showing undefined.

Comment: Correct.  Thats what you told it to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, the name of the radio buttons is `'Q7yesno'`, not `'7yesno'`. Replace `var x = getRadioValue('7yesno');` with `const x = getRadioValue('Q7yesno');`.

Next, to get an actual value instead of just `"on"`, set the value attribute on each radio input to match its meaning.

```html
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="Q7_check();" name="Q7yesno" id="Q7_Yes" value="yes" />
No  <input type="radio" onclick="Q7_check();" name="Q7yesno" id="Q7_No" value="no" />
```